# Sendmail is not ignoring MX lookups

Tags: linux, sendmail

I recently learned of the joys of square brackets with SMART_HOST to have sendmail ignore MX lookups. I need this functionality, however, I can't seem to make it persistant. Sending mail with -Am works, however, -bm does not. In the -Am case, the correct mail server is used. In the -bm case, an MX lookup is still being performed. Is there a way to disable MX lookups (or some working alternative)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sendmail's mailertables feature to override MX records on a per domain basis.

http://www.sendmail.org/m4/mailertables.html

Comment: didn't work. I tried doing ".bar.com smtp:[foo.bar.com]" (and numerous variations of) without luck. It still went to mx.bar.com